# Is there a way I can manage the order of multiple terminal windows

Tags: 18.04, unity

I am trying to make the migration from Ubuntu Classic to Ubuntu Unity. Sometimes for my work process I would open many terminal windows on my desktop and mentally assign a particular function to each one depending on its position on the desktop. I could then always easily return to a particular terminal window as I could infer the position based on the order they were laid out on the taskbar at the bottom.

But now with Unity I need to use the Dockbar on the side which always only shows me a single terminal window with a red dot annotation for each terminal I have open:

[image]

I then of course can get a preview of each window by clicking on this icon. But the problem now is that the order of each window in the preview continuously changes depending on what one I last activated - whereas before this was a fixed order that you could manually change.

So I can no longer infer which terminal window I want to activate based on its position. Is there any way I can force the order of these window previews not to change?

Comment: can't say about that but . Instead of multiple terminal windows open, you can go for multiple tabs which can be easily arranged :))

Comment: Or have your terminals spatially arranged on one dedicated workspace. Alt+tab brings you to these terminals, or the "dock Shortcut", i.e. <Super>+<number> with number the place of the terminal as favorite on the doc, where you can select the appropriate one. Are you sure you use Unity, or are you using the default DE of Ubuntu 18.04, which is an adapted Gnome Shell?

Comment: Its the default DE - I assumed it was Unity